# mySQL: two replicated nodes and a loadBalancer architecture

Tags: mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling, cluster-computing

I would like to have 2 nodes of mysql, that contain the same information , so if I update one it effect the other..

I also would like to have some loadbalancer to round robin between those 2 nodes.

I would like to be able to load the balance even if my app has a connection pool
the problem is that I want to start with one node, after a while add another node(to the load balancer) and I still want ~half of the connection to go to the second node..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803649/mysql-dual-master