# MySQL Failover on Two Azure Servers

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-virtual-machine, mysql-cluster

I am considering setup of two web servers in a single availability set on Azure and running a local copy of MySQL Server Community Edition on each server to save costs. The web applications on each would be identical.

I'm thinking a master/slave MySQL cluster would be the best option. So if machine 1 is the master and goes down, machine 2 can become the master or vice versa. I want to accomplish this cluster with just two machines for now but I see in the documentation the minimum system requirements are for 3 instances (2 x Data Nodes, 1 x App/Management Node)

Is there a good set of instructions for accomplishing this? (By good I mean easy to follow step-by-step sort of instructions).

Comment: Mmmmh.... dual master replication might be a better option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803649/mysql-dual-master

Comment: master-master with haproxy on each instance to control database selection

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into HaProxy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent guide on Digital Ocean that may prove useful.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication